# Clean Android screencast video

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-capture

I'd pretty much given up on the idea of being able to make a clean, professional-looking screencast to demonstrate an app. I'd looked at things like androidscreencast and whatnot, but the video is very low FPS, and you can't see where the user is touching.

Then today, I found that TweetDeck has managed to attain exactly what I've been looking for (see here: http://www.tweetdeck.com/android/).

So ... how can I create a demo video of this nature with a relatively smooth FPS and the SimFinger-like circle that makes it clear to users how to interact with the app?

Comment: For an even better example, see their video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDc9fDLlhq8&feature=player_embedded

Comment: Found this: http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/android/how-to-capture-screenshots-and-record-video-on-android-device.xhtml Maybe something for you?

Comment: @Lukas: Yeah, that's one of the super-chunky, low FPS and no "finger" indicator solutions I referenced above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, that's a desktop screencasting utility, applied to the 2.2 or lower emulator, on a fast machine.

Comment: And that would be okay. Any guess as to where the virtual finger comes from, though?

Comment: @Blumer: Some desktop screencasting tools do that, as part of highlighting the mouse pointer. Camtasia does, for example.

Comment: What about changing your Mouse-cursor to something like this finger?

Comment: The emulator overrides the windows pointer to its own black w/ white outline cursor. :(

Comment: But yes! That was it, Commonsware! I downloaded the cursor file found here: http://www.neathings.com/2011/02/04/improve-your-app-demo-video-with-a-virtual-finger/ and then used the "Effects" options in Camtasia to replace the cursor with that one. It still shows a normal pointer at the time that you're recording the video, but it is replaced with the custom cursor in playback.

Comment: @Blumer: Glad to hear it works for you. Though that blog post you link to is a bit scary -- exactly *which* finger is it giving you? :-)

Comment: The virtual finger might also come from the developer options on the android device. Activate "Show touches" there.